# Custom TableViewCell changing values randomly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I'm having a problem. I have a Custom UITableViewCel, the cell contains a slider which changes a value on a label on the cell. When clicking on the cell and then moving the table, the value replicates itself on another cell and then changes the value to a different cell, resetting it's value to 0.

For demonstration purposes:

**First setting the value**

[image]

Clicking on a random cell then returns:

A totally different cell with the same data that was not put there.

[image]

And then when returning back to the cell where the value was first set:

[image]

The value is back to 0

Can anyone help me here:

My Slider value changed code;

```
labelSliderVal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", sliderSlider.value];
if(sliderSlider.value < 30)
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else if(sliderSlider.value > 60)
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
} else {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

And my UITableViews `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

***Commented out***

```
/*
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];

}*/
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellView" owner:nil options:nil];
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        for(id currentObj in nibObjs)
        {
            if([currentObj isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObj;
            }

        }
    }

    GradeToolAppDelegate * appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    Module *aModule = [appDelegate.modules4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    AssessmentDetail *anAssess = [aModule.assessmentDetails4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.sliderSlider.tag = indexPath.row;  
    cell.labelAssessment.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", anAssess.assessmentName4];
    cell.labelAssessmentType.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", anAssess.assessmentType4];
    cell.labelWeighting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", anAssess.assessmentWeighting4];
    cell.labelDueDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", anAssess.assessmentDueDate4];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a cell re-use issue.  It also seems that the cells are being used (or trying to be used) to "hold" the data instead of just displaying it.  If you post the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, people might be able to give you more specific advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization

```
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSInteger numberOfSections = [myTableView numberOfSections];
for ( int section = 0; section < numberOfSections ; section++ ) {
    NSInteger       numberOfRows   = [myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    NSMutableArray *sectionResults = [NSMutableArray array];

    [results addObject:sectionResults];

    for ( int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++ ) {
        [sectionResults addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
    }
}
```

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`,

```
...
NSArray *sectionResults = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSNumber *number = [sectionResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

slider.value = [number floatValue];

...
```

In `sliderValueChanged:`,

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)slider.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSArray *sectionResults = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    ...
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:slider.value];
    cell.sliderValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", slider.value];

    [sectionResults replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:number];
    ...
}
```

Code for `totalForSection:`,

```
- (float) totalForSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex {
    NSArray *sectionResults = [results objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];
    float result = 0.0;

    for (NSNumber *number in sectionResults) {
        result += [number floatValue];
    }

    return result;
}

- (float)sumTotal {
    float result = 0.0;
    NSinteger numberOfSections = [myTableView numberOfSections];
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++ ) {
        result += [self totalForSection:i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Initial Answer**

Well this is happening because of reusable cells. You will need to store the state of the contents and update the cell accordingly in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  On slider value change,

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)slider.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    AssessmentDetail *anAssessment = [module.assessmentDetails4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    anAssessment.property = slider.value;
    cell.propertyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", slider.value];
}
```

Now both the model and the label have been changed. So next time cell is reused, the label should get the right value.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have added my cellForRowAtIndexPath if there is anything that should be changed, I will update my code to reflect certain changes you've made

Comment: What value varies based on the slider?

Comment: The value property of the slider is only used, the slider moves, updates a label on the cell and that's it

Comment: You will have to save the data outside the cell for this to work correctly. You will probably need to maintain an additional array for this. Otherwise you wont be able to get this right. The method for total from the previous question is also likely to fail as the table view won't keep the off screen cells alive and instead reuse them. So you will lose all that data on scrolling. Hence it is necessary to maintain an array or an array of arrays based on the requirement here to get the total and maintain consistency.

Comment: I really don't know how I can implement this, are there any pointers you can give?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I now have an idea on what to do